# Use of encryption and storage of personal information on website based in India

Tags: business, india, encryption

I want to launch a website that stores users' personal information, encrypts user passwords, and uses SSL for secure transmission. Do I require an license to launch the website? If yes, how do I obtain a license in India? I don't have a registered office and am hosting my website on a third-party server.

Answer (score 1):

No. You do not require any license for this. Section 43 A of the Information technology Act explicitly provides that

> Where a body corporate, possessing, dealing or handling any sensitive
>   personal data or information in a computer resource which it owns,
>   controls or operates, is negligent in implementing and maintaining
>   reasonable security practices and procedures and thereby causes
>   wrongful loss or wrongful gain to any person, such body corporate
>   shall be liable to pay damages by way of compensation to the person so
>   affected

So you could literally just purchase a domain+hosting and start collecting data. However, you should use sufficient security to prevent it from being hacked because that would be punishable as outlined by Section 72 A which states:

> Punishment for disclosure of information in breach of lawful contract.
>   -Save as otherwise provided in this Act or any other law for the time being in force, any person including an intermediary who, while
>   providing services under the terms of lawful contract, has secured
>   access to any material containing personal information about another
>   person, with the intent to cause or knowing that he is likely to cause
>   wrongful loss or wrongful gain discloses, without the consent of the
>   person concerned, or in breach of a lawful contract, such material to
>   any other person, shall be punished with imprisonment for a term which
>   may extend to three years, or with fine which may extend to five lakh
>   rupees, or with both

Certain data are treated differently such as credit and debit card details, sensitive data, etc. So I would recommend you to read the [Information Technology (Reasonable Security Practices and Procedures and Sensitive Personal Data or Information) Rules, 2011](http://www.wipo.int/edocs/lexdocs/laws/en/in/in098en.pdf) to know your liabilities.